# Binding Object to Form in Liferay

Tags: java, spring, liferay

Asked on Liferay forum post https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/75068520

Hi, is there any way to natively bind an Object to a form within a Liferay portlet and send it to a `@Controller` (possibly as a `@ModelAttribute`)? With Thymeleaf we can do this with the `th:object` attribute on a form, and I believe Spring forms can do this though I've never implemented one myself. I'm reading up on this but am wondering if Liferay provides this out the box.

Thanks for any input!